# "Unable to get printer status" error with network printer installed with CUPS

Tags: networking, printing, cups-lpd

In an Ubuntu PC, I added a network printer through the CUPS web gui (it is an HP LaserJet Professional P1102), with the following url

```
http://my_host_name:631/printers/HP_LaserJet_Professional_P1102
```

Then I added the printer to other computers (a Windows and a Mac one), and they correctly detected it. However when I try to send a document to the printer, with one of the three computers (Ubuntu included), the following error appears both in the CUPS web gui and in the Properties window of the Ubuntu Printer Setting:

```
Unable to get printer status
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 5):

You have already connected your printer your LAN via wifi and connected the printer to your Ubuntu pc. Or at least your pc detected the printer.

The reason the connection did not work with me, is because I had `http://printer_ip` instead of `ipp://printer_ip` as the connection URI.

So in my CUPS web gui, I see something like this now:

`Description:   Canon PIXUS MG3530
Location:

Driver: Canon PIXUS MG3530 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.11 (color, 2-sided printing)
Connection: ipp://192.168.0.110
Defaults:   job-sheets=none, none media=iso_a4_210x297mm sides=one-sided`

Hope this helps.

Comment: In the end I used a different setting of the shared printer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AreTor would you care to share? What setting did you change?

Comment: @Twonky I added the printer through the `Add Printer` interface, specifying its IP address and selecting the printer with `Queue: PASSTHRU`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by manually inserting the printer IP address like in this answer: [how-do-i-modify-a-printers-ip-address-in-cups#913534](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913480/how-do-i-modify-a-printers-ip-address-in-cups#913534)

Somehow CUPS wasn't able to handle the url anymore, although it was still capable of correctly identifying the printer.

Hope it helps (it took days for me to figure it out!)