# How do I modify a printer's IP address in CUPS?

Tags: printing

I have a network printer with a static IP address. Recently I've changed my subnet and had to allocate it a new static IP address.

I've tried to update CUPS with the new IP address by going to Printers -> [Printer name] -> Administration -> Modify printer -> Current connection -> Continue. I'm presented with this screen but the connection string is not an editable box, so I can't change the IP address:

[image: CUPS screenshot]

How can I modify the IP address?

Comment: I believe you can do it command line like in this answer:  https://serverfault.com/a/36587/289128

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've never had much joy from the CUPS web interface.

You can change the printer URL here, at least if your setup is similar to mine.

Preferences/Printers, right click and choose Properties

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm using i3 on Xubuntu, so it isn't of much use for me, but might be useful for other users. What DE is that? Do you happen to know the name of the binary for that application?

Comment: I use Lubuntu, LXDE on Ubuntu, and stock Ubuntu; the printer dialog screen is the same for all. The name of the application is `system-config-printer`

Comment: Great, I can confirm that I have that in Xubuntu (Xfce).

Comment: I've changed the accepted answer to this one as it more directly answers the question (modify the existing printer rather than delete/recreate a new one).

Comment: Works well!  +1  =)

Answer (score 22):

You can edit /etc/cups/printers.conf

In a terminal:
`sudo systemctl stop cups`

`sudo vi /etc/cups/printers.conf` - (or the text editor of your choice, I chose vi.)

locate the printer's URI (**in bold below**), it will be among all of your printers' profiles, they are arranged within tags like:

> <Printer My Poop Laser Printer>
> PrinterId 1
> UUID urn:uuid:c41ca0c7-52f3-3448-5dfe-11281fc3ac2e
> AuthInfoRequired none
> Info
> Location
> MakeModel Generic IPP Everywhere Printer
> **DeviceURI ipp://192.168.200.2/printers/laser**
> State Idle
> .
> .
> </Printer>

You can edit the IP there, save it.
And then restart cups...

`sudo systemctl restart cups`

Comment: +1  This is the easiest and best answer in my opinion.  =)

Comment: +1 for Printer My Poop Laser Printer

Comment: +1 this worked for me, however had to reboot for it to take effect

Answer (score 8):

The IP address is not a modifiable field, because, if you changed it, it would describe a different printer.

Abandon the "Modify Printer" approach, and on `http://localhost:631/admin`, `Find New Printer`

Comment: This worked, but I also had to run my printer setup program after I "found" the "new printer". I have an HP printer, and in my case, I ran "hp-setup".

Answer (score 2):

I just went through the same exercise when my subnet changed.  You *can* modify the  connection.  However, you will *not* be able to select current connection.  You have to select a "new" connection, i.e., LPD or AppSocket or, for you, ipp.  As your original/current connection is ipp, chose Internet protocol printing (ipp).  Hit continue and fill out details the as current connection.

Answer (score 0):

As root in a terminal window do, for example:

```
lpadmin -p HL2270DW -v http://192.168.1.102:631
```

Of course, substitute your own printer's name after `-p`. You don't have to do anything within the CUPS interface.