# How to change the IP address of an installed printer?

Tags: networking, 20.04, printing

I installed an HP printer from a local network. Now, for some reason, the internal address of the printer has changed from 10.0.0.3 to 10.0.0.2. I opened the printer setting, but cannot change the IP address from there:

[image]

Is there another way to change the printer's address?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1267529/15811

Answer (score 2):

From this tutorial: [Assigning an HP Network Printer a Fixed IP Address](https://computerchimp.com/troubleshooting/assigning-an-hp-network-printer-a-fixed-ip-address.html)

### Setting a Static IP Address

Once you know your printer’s IP address, entering it is pretty easy. Here’s what you do:

1. Run your Web browser.
2. In the Web browser’s address bar, type the IP address of your printer and press Enter. Assuming you entered the right address, the HP printer control panel should appear.
3. Click the Networking tab.
4. Under Connections, click Wired.

[image: hp ip config.jpg]